# How to reverse or repeat RotateTransform?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation

I followed a tutorial on rotating a picture bound to a button and it should be pretty simple, yet I can't figure it out.

```
private void rotateMenu()
{
    int rotateAngle;

    if (menuState) rotateAngle = -90;
    else rotateAngle = 90;

    DoubleAnimation myanimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, rotateAngle, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(222)));

    var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform(rotateAngle, 24.5, 24.5);
    menuButtonImage.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;

    rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, myanimation);

}
```

First button press - rotate the picture by 90 degrees. Simple, works.

Now I want to either reverse the rotation or rotate another 90 degrees. 
Animation works fine but the outcome always switches back to the picture being rotated 90 degrees, no matter what I set the second `rotateAngle` to.

Basically what I get is in the first part of the picture, want I need in the second part.

[image: Basically what I get is in the first part of the Pic, want I need in the second part.]

What am I doing wrong here? Why can't I rotate the picture again? I tried with -90, 90 and lots of other values, e.g. 45 degrees, yet no rotation happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the picture isn't actually rotated, but it's only rendered rotated. Until the rendertransform gets a new transform, it will stay rotated.

This will rotate it back, So you could try:

```
DoubleAnimation myanimation2 = 
    new DoubleAnimation(0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(222)));
```

only use the `toValue` parameter overload to rotate it back.

---

I would make something like:

```
// initial angle is 0
RotateTransform _rotateTransform = new RotateTransform(0.0, 24.5, 24.5);
Duration _rotationSpeed;

private void CreateRotation()
{
    _rotationSpeed = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(222));
    menuButtonImage.RenderTransform = _rotateTransform;
}


private void rotateToSide()
{
    DoubleAnimation myanimation = new DoubleAnimation(90, _rotationSpeed);

    _rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, myanimation);

}

private void rotateToDefault()
{
    DoubleAnimation myanimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, _rotationSpeed);

    _rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, myanimation);

}
```

---

For your information (as I can read from your code) You don't have to change the `Angle` property of the `rotateTransform` object. The `rotateTransform.BeginAnimation` will alter the property.

Comment: You may also consider to set (only) the DoubleAnimation's `By` property to rotate by a certain amount without having to know the start or end values.

Comment: You want to set it to a target angle. If the image is already rotated, it will stay that way. Even if the previous animation is active, it will cancel the previous and will rotate back without glitching. (i've never used `By`) you don't want the image to be other than 0 or 90 degrees

Comment: I was referring to the "repeat" behaviour mentioned in the question title. To repeatedly rotate by 90 degrees, just set `By`to 90.

Comment: But if you click again before the previous animation is completed, it might get the wrong target value because the running animation is terminated. (i say might, because it didn't tested it)